# C code cant run select query in cron

Tags: mysql, c, linux, shell, cron

We have a C code as below. This is how we have compiled it gcc -o get1Receive $(mysql_config --cflags) get1ReceiveSource.c $(mysql_config --libs) -lrt. I works fine when we run from the terminal. Then we tried to run it using cron job and when we review this two line printf("\nNumf of fields : %d",num_fields); and printf("\nNof of row : %lu",mysql_num_rows(localRes1));. The first line shows 4 as the value and second line never give any values and is always 0. We have took the same select query and run on the db and confirm there is value but it is just not delivering when running via cron job.The script is given executable permission too.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>

int flag = 0;



int main () {
                  MYSQL *localConn;
                  MYSQL_RES *localRes1;
                  MYSQL_ROW localRow1;
                  char *server = "localhost";
                  char *user = "user1";
                  char *password = "*****"; 
                  char *database = "test1";
                  localConn = mysql_init(NULL);
                  if (!mysql_real_connect(localConn, server,
                         user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
                      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(localConn));
                      exit(1);
                  }

            struct timeval tv;
          char queryBuf1[500],queryBuf2[500];
          char buff1[20] = {0};
          char buff2[20] = {0};
          gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
          //fprintf (stderr, "[%d.%06d] Flag set to 1 on ", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
          //tv.tv_sec -= 5;
          strftime(buff1, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00", localtime(&tv.tv_sec));
          strftime(buff2, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:59", localtime(&tv.tv_sec));
          printf("\nTime from %s", buff1);
          printf("\nTime to %s", buff2);

          sprintf(queryBuf1,"SELECT ipDest, macDest,portDest, sum(totalBits) FROM dataReceive WHERE timeStampID between '%s' And '%s'  GROUP BY ipDest, macDest, portDest ",buff1,buff2);
                printf("\nQuery receive %s",queryBuf1);


                if(mysql_query(localConn, queryBuf1))
                {
                    printf("Error in first query of select %s\n",mysql_error(localConn));
                    exit(1);
                }

                localRes1 = mysql_store_result(localConn);
                int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(localRes1);

                printf("\nNumf of fields : %d",num_fields);
                printf("\nNof of row : %lu",mysql_num_rows(localRes1));

                while((localRow1 = mysql_fetch_row(localRes1)) !=NULL)
                {
                  int totalBits = atoi(localRow1[3]);

                  printf("totalBits %d\n", totalBits);
                  printf("RECEIVE %s,%s\n", localRow1[0], localRow1[1]);
                  if(totalBits>5000)
                  {
                    sprintf(queryBuf1,"INSERT INTO alertReceive1 (timeStampID,ipDest, macDest, portDest, totalBits)VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s',%s)",buff1, localRow1[0],localRow1[1],localRow1[2],localRow1[3]);
                    printf("Query 1 before executing %s\n",queryBuf1);
                    if (mysql_real_query(localConn,queryBuf1,strlen(queryBuf1))) {
                   printf("Error in first insert %s\n",mysql_error(localConn));
                   fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(localConn));
                   exit(1);
                   }
                    //printf("Query 1 after executing %s\n",queryBuf1);*/
                   }    
                } 


          mysql_free_result(localRes1); 
          mysql_close(localConn);


}
```

We have run this command file get1Receive and resulting to

```
file get1Receive
get1Receive.c: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

We have also run this command * * * * *  set > /tmp/myvars and below is the results.

```
GROUPS=()
HOME=/root
HOSTNAME=capture
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
IFS='
'
LOGNAME=root
MACHTYPE=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
OPTERR=1
OPTIND=1
OSTYPE=linux-gnu
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
POSIXLY_CORRECT=y
PPID=11086
PS4='+ '
PWD=/root
SHELL=/bin/sh
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments:posix
SHLVL=1
TERM=dumb
UID=0
USER=root
_=/bin/sh
```

Comment: Put the `\n` at the end of `printf` format strings, not the beginning. Also, call `fflush(NULL)` if appropriate. Compile with `gcc -Wall -g`. Improve the code till no warnings are given. Use `snprintf` not `sprintf`

Comment: Have you tested this from the command line with the same shell and user as used by cron job?

Comment: Please indent your code appropriately, and improve the formatting and formulation of your question.

Comment: @suspectus yes I did from the same shell. I purposely ran with root so there wont be any permission issue.

Comment: But precisely, if running as root, you can't get the permission issues that `cron` may have encountered.

Comment: Yes that is why I purposely run from root.

Comment: So, assuming the `crontab` job is not root, you did not test on the terminal your program as the non-root user `cron` is running for.

Comment: @No I am running everything as root for now to discount the permission issue possibilities. I am running on the terminal as root and also the cron job as root.

Comment: Have you considered doing this in pure SQL, eg `INSERT INTO alertReceive1 (timeStampID,ipDest, macDest, portDest, totalBits) SELECT ipDest, macDest,portDest, sum(totalBits) FROM dataReceive WHERE timeStampID between $1 And $2 GROUP BY ipDest, macDest, portDest )` ?

Comment: @wildplasser not on the cron job but terminal yes it works perfectly fine

Comment: @wildplasser I have confirm that when it comes to insert or query in cron it just fails to work.

Comment: Wrap it in a shell script, preferrably in a here-document. (mysql's silly backticks could interfere, but you can work around that)

Comment: @wildplasser previously I have tried that too. IT still didnt work either what could be silly mysql backticks will be any resolution to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic hints (see also my comments):

- Take time to **read documentation** notably from [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) (which you can also get by typing `man man` or `man 2 intro` on the terminal, etc etc...), and [MySQL 5.5 reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index.html). Be sure to understand what `GIYF` or `STFW` means.
- Put the `\n` at the end of `printf` format strings, not the beginning.
- Also, call `fflush(NULL)` if appropriate, notably before any MySQL queries e.g. before your `mysql_real_query` calls, and at the end of your `while` loops
- Compile with `gcc -Wall -g` e.g. with the following command in your terminal

  ```
  gcc -Wall -g $(mysql_config --cflags) get1ReceiveSource.c \
             $(mysql_config --libs) -lrt -o get1Receive
  ```
- Improve the code till no warnings are given. (You may even want to have `-Wall -Wextra` instead of just `-Wall`). Don't forget to use a version control system like `git`.
- use the `gdb` debugger (you need to [learn](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) how to use it).

  <sup>(only once you are sure there is no more bugs in your code replace `-g` by `-O2 -g` in your compilation command)</sup>
- use `sizeof`; most occurrences of `20` should be a `sizeof`, or at the very least use `#define SMALLSIZE 20` and then only `SMALLSIZE` not `20`.
- Use `snprintf` not `sprintf` (and test its result size, which should fit!). [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) takes an extra size argument, e.g.

  ```
   if (snprintf(querybuf, sizeof querybuf,
                "SELECT ipDest, macDest, portDest, sum(totalBits)"
                " FROM dataReceive"
                " WHERE timeStampID between '%s' And '%s' "
                " GROUP BY ipDest, macDest, portDest ",
                buff1, buff2) >= (int) (sizeof querybuf))
       abort();
  ```
- consider using [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) with `openlog`, and look into your system logs.

I don't see how is `queryBuf1` declared. (Your code, as posted, probably don't even compile!). You might want something like `char querybuf[512];` ...

And most importantly, calling `mysql_real_query` inside a `mysql_fetch_row` loop is **wrong**: you should have fetched all the rows before issuing the next MySQL query. Read more about [MySQL C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c.html).

You also forgot to test the result `localRes1` of `mysql_store_result(localConn)`;  show somehow (perhaps thru `syslog`) the `mysql_error(localConn)` when `localRes1` is `NULL` ....

Comment: @Where should I call the fflush any tips that? How to compile gcc -Wall -g I am not clear what you are saying here?

Comment: Compile with the `-Wall -g` options to `gcc`

Comment: Where to put -Wall -g at the end or after the -o I have add the queryBuf1 lines too. I dont understand why and how to use snprintf is it the same with sprintf ?

Comment: Please take the habit to read the documentation of every command and library function you are using. Otherwise, you are going nowhere!

Comment: ok I will try to learn as I am quite new to it regarding the second mysql_real_query is for me to perform the insert statement.

Comment: I have compile using the -Wall -g and below are the two warning warning: implicit declaration of function âgettimeofdayâ gettimeofday (&tv, NULL); and warning: format â%luâ expects type âlong unsigned intâ, but argument 2 has type âmy_ulonglongâ
which is referring to printf("\nNof of row : %lu",mysql_num_rows(localRes1));

Comment: How to get the time of day then if I have to follow this warning?

Comment: Please, **take the habit of reading documentation**. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html documents the needed `#include`, so follow that! And http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html  documents the `%lld` format specifier for a `long long` argument. Again, you are going nowhere if you don't **read documentation**; you'll spend much less time reading than blindly trying and debugging your code!

Comment: @Sorry basile now at least u referred me to the right document I shall get into it first.

Comment: I am done even with Wextra gcc -Wall -g $(mysql_config --cflags) get1ReceiveSource.c            $(mysql_config --libs) -lrt -o get1Receive no more warning.

Comment: I tried the -02 -g gcc -Wall -Wextra -02 -g $(mysql_config --cflags) get1ReceiveSource.c            $(mysql_config --libs) -lrt -o get1Receive also no more warning in it.

Comment: Don't try that before several days of debugging with `gdb` and testing

Comment: sorry when I put this codes if (snprintf(queryBuf1, sizeof queryBuf1,
              "SELECT ipDest, macDest, portDest, sum(totalBits)"
              " FROM dataReceive"
              " WHERE timeStampID between '%s' And '%s' "
              " GROUP BY ipDest, macDest, portDest ",
              buff1, buff2) >= sizeof queryBuf1))
            abort(); I got this errors warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions and error: expected statement before â)â token and at the very top I define this #define SMALLSIZE 20; before the main.

Comment: I incorrectly added an extra right parenthesis and removed it just now. Also I just casted the right operand of `>=`; you should have done that without asking.

Comment: ok it compiles well no issues at all. But I dont you get you #define SMALLSIZE 20; how this works?

Comment: It is also time to read a good C programming book. I don't have time to explain the *C* programming language here....

Comment: ok I will read as I go along and test more stuff. Now since I dont get any error and warning what should I try to run the codes ready?